# Using apache mod_alias in vhost to link assets from external server

Tags: apache, alias, virtualhost, assets, mod-alias

This is an outside shot I know. I am supporting a site that has constantly changing assets that are excluded from the repository for obvious reasons. Currently I am having to FTP these assets to my local computer in order to develop and test properly. What I want to do is simply link to the assets on the server. I thought this might be possible using Apache's mod_alias, but I cant get it to work:

```
Alias /assets http://www.mysite.com/assets
```

Is this possible? Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mod_proxy to make Apache fetch resources from a remote server and then return them under that URL:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /assets http://www.mysite.com/assets
ProxyPassReverse /assets http://www.mysite.com/assets
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: yes (+1), mod_alias is a way to map an url to a **local** filesystem resource. Mapping an external web resource is the job of a proxy.

Comment: what if you wanted to create the redirection from a virtual host? I mean to make `http://mysite.localhost` point to `http://www.mysite.com`... how would you proceed?

Comment: @Jago  same way, just use the directives above inside your vhost definition and add `ServerName mysite.com` and `ServerAlias www.mysite.com`.  You just need to ensure DNS for `mysite.com` resolves to your vhost mysite.localhost definition.